# Whether the complete library will get loaded to memory (RAM) while execution of a program?

Tags: c++, c, linux

How it will be different in case of static and dynamic library?

I am having understanding of static and dynamic library creation and use, but I am having doubt regarding loading of library to primary memory. whether static/dynamic library will get fully loaded to RAM if we are calling only one function from library.

e.g. consider we are having 10mb size of library and we are calling only one function from that library whether complete library will get loaded or only the called function object code will get load? and is it same in case of static and dynamic library?(if we are using static library executable size will be more but what about loading time)

thanks in advance!

Comment: these shared libaries are shared across the whole system. so a hundred programs all use the same math library, but its only mapped into memory once. i wouldn't worry about something like this if the library is common

Comment: static libraries on the other hand are optimally linked, so that only the fewest .o's necessary from inside the .a are added to the executable file as you are compiling.

Comment: @Steve: You mean, it's mapped once per address space. Also, only the never-written portions are shared (barring KSM).

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't think this question really warrents being that specific. and the 'library'  that is mentioned here is pretty clearly referencing the text of the library which is by definition already never-written.

Answer (score 6):

Linux (as all modern OS with on-demand-paging) will map your whole library on load, but only page in those pages it has to read, e.g.: Init the libraries, Resolve all external (non-delayed) symbols.

Those tasks are mostly delegated to a user-mode dynamic loader.

Parts of your images never written, or remerged afterwards by KSM (Kernel Samepage Merger), can be stored only once, relieving memory pressure.

Answer (score 3):

> When dynamic linking is needed, the kernel bootstraps the dynamic
>   linker (ELF interpreter), which initializes itself, and then loads the
>   specified shared objects (unless already loaded).

[IBM: Anatomy of Linux dynamic libraries](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-dynamic-libraries/)